# Why do React development files persist in production build?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, bundle, react-dom

I'm relatively new to React and currently I'm trying to optimize my site's performance.

While running performance reports, I've noticed that the development files — that I assume should not be in the production bundle — are still present in bundle.js.

Here are the dependencies inside package.json used in the building of the production bundle:

```
"dependencies": {
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-inlinesvg": "^3.0.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-toolkit": "^1.1.2",
"request": "^2.88.2",
"sass": "^1.52.1",
"serve": "^13.0.2",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
```

The website is currently hosted on Heroku from a Github repo, and Heroku is also responsible for running all the npm run build commands.

Here is Heroku build log (in case needed):

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.15.0...
       Using default npm version: 8.5.5
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       
       up to date, audited 2239 packages in 6s
       
       217 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       29 vulnerabilities (28 high, 1 critical)
       
       To address issues that do not require attention, run:
         npm audit fix
       
       To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Some issues need review, and may require choosing
       a different dependency.
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > test-task@0.1.0 build
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
         92.84 kB  build/static/js/main.856ade89.js
         2.33 kB   build/static/css/main.b352c60b.css
         1.78 kB   build/static/js/787.e8769ff5.chunk.js
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
         npm install -g serve
         serve -s build
       
       Find out more about deployment here:
       
         https://cra.link/deployment
       
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       removed 18 packages, and audited 1560 packages in 4s
       
       194 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       8 vulnerabilities (7 high, 1 critical)
       
       To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Some issues need review, and may require choosing
       a different dependency.
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 81.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v12
```

I assume the packages to look into are "react-dom" and "react" since these are shown in reports as still using dev files(see picture attached), but shouldn't `npm run build` switch their settings to production mode? And seeing that the performance report also complains about the need in further minification of js bundle, could it mean that all this is just the matter of Heroku buildpack not applying effective optimization rules?

[image: performance report]

Appreciate your help.